# How to show detail of previous and next list items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

In my program i am fetching data from json and storing into arraylist and then populating into ListView, once user do tap on any of the list item showing record in another activity, where i have two buttons, namely:- previous & next, and now i want whenever user do tap on Previous button (need to show previous list item detail) and Next button (need to show next list item detail).....

here is my code i am using to fetch data and to show detail of tapped item

**DetailActivity.java:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        // add cast to ArrayList<Actors>
        final ArrayList<Actors> arrayList= (ArrayList<Actors>) bundle.getSerializable("information");
        final int currentindex = bundle.getInt("index");
        final Actors actors = arrayList.get(currentindex);

        textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);

        for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)
        {             
           textName.setText(actors.getName());             
        }

        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  int currentindex;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    // add cast to ArrayList<Actors>
    final ArrayList<Actors> arrayList= (ArrayList<Actors>)  bundle.getSerializable("information");
      currentindex = bundle.getInt("index");
    textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
    textName.setText(""+arrayList.arrayList.get(currentindex).getName());
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            currentindex=currentindex+1;
            if(currentindex<arrayList.size()){
                 textName.setText(""+arrayList.get(currentindex).getName());
            }
            else{
                currentindex=currentindex-1;
            }


        }
    });

    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            currentindex=currentindex-1;
            if(currentindex>=0){
                 textName.setText(""+arrayList.get(currentindex).getName());
            }
            else{
                currentindex=currentindex+1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: great solution, using easiest way of doing this :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the JSON collected arraylist with selected index to next launching activity and than based on the current selection get the -1 and +1 etc position and get the value from your collection to display particulr position information

Do something like below on lciking to launch nre activity

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contactList ", contactList );
        intent.putExtra("current", pos);
```

In the next activity Do something like below

```
ArrayList<String > contactList contactList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("contactList ");
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("current", 0);
        contactList.get(position);

        //for previous do
        contactList.get(position-1);
        //for next do
        contactList.get(position+1);
```

Comment: can you show me the way, by using my existing code ?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contactList ", contactList );
        intent.putExtra("current", pos);

just do something like this and get the same contactList in next activity and get the current selected value from contactList to display current and do + or _ to get previous next value from contactList arraylist

Comment: please, check my updated answer, tried your solution

Comment: When you are passing you arraylist than you don't need to pass any other values like name, email etc. Same you can get using position from passed arraylist to launching activity. I just updated my post with clean code. Just follow that. It should give you expected what you are trying to achieve.